# Page is hanging when submitting the form in php

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I am trying to submit a form using jQuery and ended up hanging the page. I have this one page which have listing and have used table for that. For each listing i am giving edit option. So when user click on edit button on the row, a form will drop below the `tr` tag and update button. When i click on the update button, page start loading but it keeps loading forever.

This is my form (Sample), I have `foreach` for listing, so for each row, we have a new form separated with id.

```
<form action="" class="edit_form 1" method="POST">
    <div class="row filter-row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="focus-label">Order Id</label>
                <input type="text" name="order_id" class="form-control floating order_id" value="">
                <div class="orderid_error text-danger form_error"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-primary submit-btn test_update" data-test_id="1" name="testupdate" type="button" value="test_update">Update</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).on("click",".test_update",function(){
    var test_id     = $(this).attr("data-test_id");
    if(typeof test_id!="undefined" && test_id!=""){
        $(".edit_form."+test_id).submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by hang?

Comment: in inspect element network tab what is your request result?

Comment: hang means, it just keep loading and if it is loading and you click on any other link within the page, it will not work. Event if you copy paste the url again, it won't work. I have to clean the cache and then page will load again. Network tab is blank.

Comment: In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); **they cannot start with a digit**, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit.

Comment: Digit in the form class is basically the id of the form. As I mentioned in my question, for my each row i have one form and to mark the form as unique, i have to attach id with class.

Comment: So what you have here is a series of forms *with the same id* (`edit`), but then you attach a *unique identifier* to a *class*? Didn't this seem at least a little bit wrong? Note that having multiple elements with the same id is not valid html.

Comment: Do you see any errors or other messages in the console?

Comment: @El_Vanja you are right. I am having same id for multiple form. But now i have removed all the id from the form and working with class only still facing the same issue

Comment: @kmoser no error at all

Comment: Why is the event handler calling `submit()` when the event was already called by clicking a `<button type="submit">`? Also, what URL is the form POSTing to? Maybe the server is hanging.

Comment: actually i have to validation of the form on our side so that is why calling submit once validation clears. Also changed the button type from submit to button but it didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: The point of my comment was not to remove the id from the forms. It was to point out you were placing *ids* into *class* instead of placing it into *id*. Class is not meant to represent a unique element.

Comment: it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning multiple forms on a single page might be occurring the issue. Since you are using jQuery to submit the form, there is a workaround for the same.

Do not create your form inside the `foreach`, instead just create one form with empty input box and assign the value through jQuery and then submit the form.

```
<form id="example" action="" class="edit_form 1" method="POST">
<div class="row filter-row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="focus-label">Order Id</label>
            <input id="orderid" type="text" name="order_id" class="form-control floating order_id" value="">
            <div class="orderid_error text-danger form_error"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-primary submit-btn test_update" data-test_id="1" name="testupdate" type="button" value="test_update">Update</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on("click",".test_update",function(){
    var test_id     = $(this).attr("data-test_id");
    if(typeof test_id!="undefined" && test_id!=""){
       $("#orderid").val("YOUR VALUE");
       $("#example").submit();
    }
});
```

This will definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is over here:
$(".edit_form."+test_id).submit();

jQuery searches for the element with class value as => 'edit_form.1' which does not exist in the code.

For this to work you need to have a unique id for every form(assuming you've already done it as you mentioned).
Try this:

```
$(document).on("click",".test_update",function(){
var test_id     = $(this).attr("data-test_id");
if(typeof test_id!="undefined" && test_id!=""){
    $(this).parent().parent().submit();
}
});
```

Since in the DOM nodes every button will be differently saved even though it has same class it shouldn't be a problem adding parent() as it will call the parent of the clicked element but not all the buttons with the class name.

Let me know if it worked.  :)

Comment: 'edit_form.1' is the class name of our form.

Comment: class="edit_form 1"  , you gave this as your class so 'edit_form' and  '1' will be separately considered as different classes. 

Also i wouldn't recommend using a 'dot'(.) in between of a class name.

Comment: In jQuery or CSS, if you are accessing such class, you have to 'dot'(.) in between of a class name

Comment: Yes My bad, agreed, you can do that in jQuery. Also I have tried running your code locally and it worked as expected for me.